# Expanding Zip Codes From County Level For Multiple Vendors

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, powerbi

I will try and explain this as best as possible.

1. I have a table in excel/powerbi that lists the servicing coverage area for a new product we are releasing at work.
2. I have a secondary table that contains state, county, zip code, fips codes, lat, long of all counties in the United States.

The first table referenced above contains a partner ID, partner state, partner county -coverage, several survey response questions, as well as the pricing information for the particular product. The issue I've run into is the need to expand each listed county (currently about 16,000 records) down to their respective zip code levels while copying down their pricing and survey response questions.

Sheet 1:

```
Col A: Partner Number
Col B: Partner Name
Col C: Partner State
Col D: Partner County
Col E: "State-County" (merged)
Col F: Survey response question 1
Col G: Survey response question 2
Col H: Product 1 Pricing quote
Col I: Product 2 pricing quote
```

Table 2:

```
Col A: State
Col B: County
Col C: ZIP Code
Col D: FIPS State
Col E: FIPS County
```

I am just about wracked in my attempts to solve this issue, I'm sure iv'e been overlooking the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) should work here:

```
=VLOOKUP(D:D,Sheet2!B:E,2)
```

Eg. Add this formula in column J of your `Sheet 1`. Note that you might need to adjust the sheet name `Sheet2!B:E` or if it contains spaces wrap it into quotes like `'Sheet 2'!B:E`.

Comment: OP says they want to expand the county to ZIP. That can't be done with a lookup. I'd recommend using the query editor to a join the tables on county and then expand out the ZIP.

Comment: @Well, then I might have misunderstood the question. And I cannot imagine how the result would look like without seeing an example.

Comment: Would you prefer if I shared a google sheet link to give a quick picture of the format of the information?

Comment: @lanB Better to include a screenshot into your original question. Links may disappear soon or later and then the question is useless for further readers. One screenshot showing how your data looks like and one example showing how the result should look like would help a lot to illustrate it I think (at least for me).